# Navbar collapse don't work bootstrap 3

Tags: navbar

I have a collapsed button in my navbar, but it doesn't work. This example have two navbar, but I need to collapsed only one navbar.

I already try different ways but I don't get to solve my problem.

The problem is that the button don't appear when the browser is minimized.

Here is the code [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/d24ynzLs)

```
    <div id="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#teste"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
      </button>        
       </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="teste">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>Forms</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms-basic.html">Basic forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms-extended.html">Extended forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms-validation.html">Validation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms-wizard.html">Wizard</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>Components</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-timeline.html">Timeline</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-pagestatistics.html">Page statistics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-sidebarwidgets.html">Sidebar widgets</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-messages.html">Messages &amp; Chat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-gallery.html">Gallery &amp; Thumbs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-tiles.html">Tiles</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-icons.html">Icons &amp; Buttons</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-elements.html">UI elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-typography.html">Typography</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-bootstrap.html">Bootstrap elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="components-grid.html">Grid</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>Tables</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables-basic.html">Basic tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables-dynamic.html">Dynamic tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables-large.html">Large tables</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>Plugins</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-charts.html">Charts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-calendar.html">Calendar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-filemanager.html">File manager</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-filetrees.html">File trees</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-elements.html">Editable elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-maps.html">Maps</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="plugins-dragdrop.html">Drag &amp; Drop widgets</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>Pages</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-error.html">Error pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Shop</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="more-shop-list.html">List view</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="more-shop-product.html">Product view</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-pricing.html">Pricing tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-faq.html">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-invoice.html">Invoice</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-userprofile.html">User profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-searchresults.html">Search results</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-login.html">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-locked.html">Lock screen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-email.html">Email templates</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more-blank.html">Blank page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Blog</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="more-blog-list.html">List big image</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="more-blog-list-small.html">List small image</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="more-blog-post.html">Post</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>Layouts</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="layouts-sidebar-hidden.html">Default hidden sidebar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="layouts-sidebar-right.html">Sidebar right side</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="layouts-color.html">Different default color</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="layouts-fixed.html">Fixed layout</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="layouts-fixed-topside.html">Fixed topbar and sidebar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#">Mobile sidebar</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="layouts-mobile-slide.html">Slide</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="layouts-mobile-button.html">Button</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="layouts-footer.html">Footer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div> 
    </div>
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is.. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this section by the looks of it.

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
```

Place this section under the div nav header.

Comment: Edited: missed a > on the end. should be ok now

Comment: ok, so what is the actually issue? as the nav bar is there, and there is a button for dropdown, but its not visable, and the brand is above the nav... please give more info on what the issue is.

Comment: Ok, i got the dropdown to work, but the hamburger menu icon is not there.. was that planned or is this also the problem?

Comment: Can you fiddle your entire html file?

Answer (score 0):

No, this section is after 3 line.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#teste"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
      </button>        
       </div>
```

[Code Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d24ynzLs/5/)